# Joining two RDDs when keys are not in the same place

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have 2 RDDs that look like this :- RDD1 elements look like this [123, 456, 789] and RDD2 tuples look like this [456, 999]. Now I need to combine/join these 2 RDDs based on 456 which is the 2nd element in RDD1 and the first element in RDD2. Final output looks something like this :- [123, 456, 789, 999]. Is there a way this can be done or do the keys need to be in the first place for the join?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: so RDD1 is made of tuples of 3 elements and RDD2 is made of tuple of 2 elements?

Comment: Yes.. that's correct.. I need to combine these 2 RDDs into tuples of 4 elements and then reduce my final joined RDD based on the last element which is 999 in this case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could convert the RDDs to Dataframe and then do a simple join as shown below.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(123, 456, 789)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(456, 999)])    
df1 = rdd1.toDF()
df2 = rdd2.toDF()
result = df1.join(df2, df1['_2'] == df2['_1'])
result.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[4])).collect()
[(123, 456, 789, 999)]
```

Comment: When I am trying this chunk of code to check whether this RDD has toDF function it returns false : print hasattr(RDD1, "tdDF"). Do I need to parallelize if these things are already RDDs?

Comment: I have pasted the scala code .. let me repost the python version

Comment: @DigvijaySawant updated the answer with pyspark version

Comment: Also I did pass the sc object to SQLContext constructor as instructed. sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)  print hasattr(RDD1, "tdDF")

Comment: @DigvijaySawant there seems to be a typo in your command, its toDF . I think you have tdDF

Comment: Stupidest thing I have done my friend.. for today. Thank you so much. Never used dataframes in pyspark before. Learned a lot. Solution works perfectly.

Comment: To add something since this creates duplicate colnames following 2 lines can be slightly modified: 
df1 = rdd1.toDF(['c1','c2','c3'])
df2 = rdd2.toDF(['c4', 'c5'])

Comment: I have updated the answer to remove column duplicates and return a RDD of tuple of 4 elements.